# Uncaught ReferenceError: FunctionName is not defined at HTMLUnknownElement.onclick

Tags: c#, button

I have an html table that shows User information and is automatically populated from a DataTable using StringBuilder and Append. I am doing it this way so that I can change the style of the data in the table depending on the values.

In the first column, I have an ASP button that I would like to click to either Enable or Disable the User on that row. The button is being generated properly (via Google Chrome inspect):

```
<asp:button class="fancyEnableButton" id="ULEnableButton4" runat="server" commandargument="4" onclick="EnableUser">Enable</asp:button>
```

...but depending on my code (I've been trying what seems like hundreds of small attempts!) either does nothing when you click it or gives the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: EnableUser is not defined at HTMLUnknownElement.onclick
```

Through lots of googling. I am pretty sure this is because it is missing its event handler?

When I create ASP buttons using the Visual Studio GUI, or when I code them in statically, they work fine so I am missing a crucial link between a static button and this one I am creating automatically.

My C# code is this which is part of the Page_Load:

```
html.Append("<asp:Button class='fancyDeleteButton' ID='ULDisableButton" + ID + "' runat='server' CommandArgument='" + ID + "' OnClick='DisableUser'>Disable</asp:button>");
```

and this is my void that I would like to run OnClick:

```
//Disable User Button
protected void DisableUser(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string userID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Label1.Text = userID;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update UserList set Enabled=0 where ID='" + userID + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

}
```

I feel like the ASP button does not know about the DisableUser function when it is being created. I have tried lots of different flavours of the OnClick command, OnClientClick and with DisableUser() etc. but nothing is working. I've also tried different ways to create the button. I must have tried 50+ different tweaks so far and nothing is working.

But I am stuck. I am new to all of this but learning quickly but I've hit a brick wall with googling and searching. Nothing is working.

What would be the best way to code in what I would like? I went with the .Append(various html); method to make the table prettier. I feel like this SHOULD be easy!

Full code C#:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _UserList : Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        //Check to make sure someone got here properly
        string checkExpertMode = Convert.ToString(Session["ExpertMode"]);
        if (checkExpertMode != "1")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Creating the table
            DataTable dt = createDataTable();
            //Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            //Table start.
            html.Append("<table class='normalTable'");
            //Building the Header row.
            html.Append("<tr>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("ID");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("Name");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("Password");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("Email Address");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("Libraries");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("Expiry Date");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("Expert Mode");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("Enabled");
            html.Append("</th>");
            html.Append("</tr>");

            //Building the Data rows.
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //Getting the data
                string ID = row[0].ToString();
                string userName = row[1].ToString();
                string password = row[2].ToString();
                string expertMode = row[3].ToString();
                string emailAddress = row[4].ToString();
                string allowedLibs = row[5].ToString();
                string enabled = row[7].ToString();

                //Checking expiry date
                string dateFlag = "";
                DateTime userExpiry = Convert.ToDateTime(row[6]);
                string shortDate = userExpiry.ToShortDateString();
                DateTime monthExpiry = userExpiry.AddMonths(-1);
                if (userExpiry < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    dateFlag = "Expired";
                }
                if (userExpiry >= DateTime.Now & monthExpiry <= DateTime.Now)
                {
                    dateFlag = "Close";
                }

                //Building the table
                html.Append("<tr style='border-top:1px solid #1678ff'>");
                //Edit Button
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append("<a href='/UserDetails.aspx?ID=" + ID + "'><button class='fancyButton' type='button'>Edit</button></a>");
                html.Append("</td>");
                //Enable/Disable button
                if (enabled == "1")
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append("<asp:Button class='fancyDeleteButton' ID='ULDisableButton" + ID + "' runat='server' CommandArgument='" + ID + "' OnClick='DisableUser'>Disable</asp:button>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                else
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append("<asp:Button class='fancyEnableButton' ID='ULEnableButton" + ID + "' runat='server' CommandArgument='" + ID + "' OnClick='EnableUser'>Enable</asp:button>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                //ID
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(ID);
                html.Append("</td>");
                //Name
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(userName);
                html.Append("</td>");
                //Password
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(password);
                html.Append("</td>");
                //Email Address
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append("<a class='tableLink' href='mailto:" + emailAddress + "''>" + emailAddress + "</a>");
                html.Append("</td>");
                //Max libraries
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append("<b>" + allowedLibs + "</b>");
                html.Append("</td>");
                //Expiry date
                if (dateFlag == "Expired")
                {
                    html.Append("<td style='color:#fc4343'>");
                    html.Append("<b>" + shortDate + "</b>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                else if (dateFlag == "Close")
                {
                    html.Append("<td style='color:#ffd422'>");
                    html.Append("<b>" + shortDate + "</b>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                else
                {
                    html.Append("<td style='color:#22d660'>");
                    html.Append("<b>" + shortDate + "</b>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                //Website expert mode
                if (expertMode == "0")
                {
                    html.Append("<td style='color:#747474'>");
                    html.Append("User");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                else
                {
                    html.Append("<td style='color:#ffd422'>");
                    html.Append("Expert");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                //Enabled?
                if (enabled == "0")
                {
                    html.Append("<td style='color:#fc4343'>");
                    html.Append("<b>Disabled</b>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                else
                {
                    html.Append("<td style='color:#22d660'>");
                    html.Append("<b>Enabled</b>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }
            //Table end
            html.Append("</table>");
            string strText = html.ToString();
            //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
            placeholder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }
    }

    //Function to create the joined datatable that shows only the libraries they have access to
    DataTable createDataTable()
    {
        string getUserInfo = "select * from UserList";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getUserInfo, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataReader sqlDR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(sqlDR);
        sqlDR.Close();
        return dt;
    }

    //Disable User Button
    protected void DisableUser(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string userID = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument.ToString();
        Label1.Text = userID;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update UserList set Enabled=0 where ID='" + userID + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

ASP

```
<% @Page Title="User List" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="_UserList" Codebehind="UserList.aspx.cs" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="main">
    <br />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I don't think you can dynamically create server-side controls out of strings like that.  In your browser's page source, if you see the `<asp:...` elements then they're not being used as server-side elements.  Whatever dynamic functionality you're looking to achieve in your page, this is not how you do it.  Perhaps instead you should have your controls defined on the page and dynamically show/hide/modify them in the code instead.

Comment: @David Thanks for the info David. Can you elaborate on how I might define the controls on the page and then show/hide them? I know how to show/hide elements but not sure how you mean in this instance.

Comment: At this point we're talking *very* generically.  But "how to define controls on the page" sounds like something to be covered by tutorials on WebForms.  (As an aside... Unless there's some compelling reason that you *have to* use WebForms, you're better off using something like MVC instead for new development.)  The same goes for interacting with those controls from code, really.  For example, if you have an `<asp:Button>` on your page then you can refer to it by its `ID` in the code and set properties on it.  e.g.: `button1.Visible = false;`

Comment: Ah so I could have a button on the page and then a generated button that calls this first button with the ID of the user a bit like you can set for="whatever"